# Java fold arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, fold

> ] [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> +[0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> +[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>
> +[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> =[0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-3,-3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Is there a Java function to do the above thing or do I have to iterate through all the lists? My smallest list is around 3k elements and an average is around 20k.

Comment: You probably have to iterate through the lists. If there is such a function, it would do the same. If you have different array lenghts then you may have a problem anyway / have to create a logic that fits your purpose (only add the first 3k (min length) for 20k elements i.e.)

Comment: If you can use Java8, it might be worthwhile to look into **streams**; especially usage of parallel streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need at least 1 `for` loop, using it's index over all the arrays, as `result[i]=arr[i]+arr2[i]+....+arrn[i];`

If the lenght varies in each array, first you need to check you are in its bounds before trying to access the element.

Comment: Yeah but it probably would be better optimised. I'll do the old fashion way then. Thanks.

Comment: maybe it can be optimised, but to access data well, you must access the data. You can not avoid to go through all elements if you must process all of them. Even if there is a more 'beautiful' way to do this, internally it must access all the concerned data.

Comment: I was just wondering if Java had an equivalent to fold in F#. It's just that my smallest ArrayList exists of 6k elements with each 1k of elements and it already takes some time to iterate through all of that (and save it). Without the saving I could save a lot of time but that would mean that there would be no concrete data.

Comment: Really don't know.. As an afterthought... What about changing the implementation and set it as map of weight - value, and process only the values inserted (no insertion to '0' value)? You may avoid many steps since your arrays seem to contain lots of 0's

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to use the Java 8 Streams. I think the `reduce()` function is equivalent to F# `fold()`. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

    int n = lists.get(0).size();
    // Reduce each column to the sum of the elements in the column
    // For example:
    //     i = 0 -> 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
    //     i = 1 -> 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 2
    IntUnaryOperator sumElementsInPosition = i -> lists.stream()
                                                       .map(l -> l.get(i))
                                                       .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);

    // For each position i, map the position to the sum of elements in that position
    List<Integer> sum = IntStream.range(0, n)
                                 .map(sumElementsInPosition)
                                 .boxed()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -3, -3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: (F# has both fold and reduce) So reduce does exist! I just did not expect that it was in 8. Thanks for that. I'll create a new version of my custom reducer with J8.

Comment: Yes, `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`, lambdas and a bunch of other functional features were introduced in Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html